# week 02 - Pioneer cohort 3: Failed to build lzma-0.0.0.3

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I am on week 02 of the 3rd Pioneer Cohort.
I am working on a Mac Mojave; when I get to running

cabal repl

I get this error:

Failed to build lzma-0.0.0.3. The failure occurred during the configure step.

I tried many things, including:

- apt install liblzma-dev
- sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev

But apt-get does not work on Mac.
So I tried

1. brew install liblzma-dev ==> failed
2. /usr/local/bin/brew install liblzma-dev ==> failed
3. /usr/local/bin/brew install liblzma-dev libglade ==> failed

I still get the same error with cabal repl

I appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wish I could comment, but I don't have that kind of reputation. Make sure you go through the setup to get nix properly installed, then do all your work through nix-shell. Specifically get your cache setup properly because it will download all the dependencies you need to run Plutus and its applications. Also, remember to checkout your plutus-apps repo to the correct tag as mentioned in a previous video Lars did before you do the `nix-shell` command. This has been floating around in a few places including here and in Discord. It helped me get setup on Catalina: https://github.com/renzwo/carda